# Text no longer displays when compiling app in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a dictionary in my application. You select your letter in the list view prior. When you click it, it opens the same ViewController for all the letters, but it determines which letter you have selected from the list view based on their number placement. All of them work except for two. The one thing these two have in common is they are the two longest letter dictionary sections. That seems to be the issue although I'm not sure how to go about fixing it so that they will display again. Here is what the code looks like when it is loaded.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    int scrollHeight;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:NO];

    if([selected intValue] == 0){
        self.title = @"A";

        content.text = @"A definitions go here. This string works";
    }
    else if([selected intValue] == 1){
        self.title = @"B";

        content.text = @"B definitions go here. This string (along with 'S') does not display";
    }
    else if([selected intValue] == 2){
        self.title = @"C";

        content.text = @"C definitions go here. This string works";
    }


    scrollHeight = 12500;
    content.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [content.text sizeWithFont:content.font 
                                        constrainedToSize:content.frame.size
                                            lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGRect newFrame = content.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    content.frame = newFrame;
    content.numberOfLines = 0;
    [content sizeToFit];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, scrollHeight);
    [mainView addSubview:scrollView];

}
```

Like I said. It works perfectly for all of them except for the two longest ones. I had updated the app and tested it on the older Xcode 4.something. These were working fine then. It wasn't until I decided to update to Xcode 5 because of gdb issues that it suddenly broke and no longer display any of the text.

Comment: So the string that you set on context.text doesn't display? Does it work if you manually set that same string (of the same length) in your if? Have you tried calling layoutIfNeeded or setNeedsDisplay on your UILabel? Did you make sure that you're contents height is not 0 after changing it?

Comment: @Olshansk Yes the string is not displaying in that particular one. This exact same code is used for all the other letters and is on the same .m. The if([selected intValue]==1) and everything it contains is the same for the other letters just different text in content.text. They are each seperated by else if ([selected intValue]==2) and so on. The two longest text strings for the letters B and S aren't working while everything else works fine. I'll look at the other things you mentioned. Contents height is as it is set and doesn't become 0.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `content`'s frame, and then calling `[content sizeToFit]`, which completely overrides any frame you may have set. Not sure what your problem is, but you can only have one or the other: either set a custom frame on the label, or `sizeToFit:`.

Comment: Ok, but it worked like this prior to updating for the ones I'm now having issues on, and it still works on all the other letters except the two with the longest string.

Comment: As in all the text displays fine for all except for the 2 longest strings.

Comment: Which don't display at all? What is "fine"?

Comment: I edited the original post. If you look at the if/else if statements it continues like that for all of the letters of the dictionary. The content of each of these letters is displayed in the content.text (ie the definitions). The two that don't work is 'B' and 'S' as their content.text strings are the 2 longest. Why they won't display doesn't make sense to me.